# How to insert values in specific index locations in a list without using insert() method?

Tags: python, list

I am quite new to Python and want to find alternative way to recreate a insert method functionality used along with lists.

```
>>> ulist = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> ulist.insert(2,9)
>>> ulist
[1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Here I want to take a input list from the user and then ask him/her the number of the place he wants to put in a new value.
And then add that value in that position, without disturbing the already existing list elements.

```
    >>> ulist = [1,2,3,4,5]
    >>> num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
    Enter the number: 2
    >>> index1 = num - 1
    >>> val = int(input("enter the value to be put at index location: "))
    enter the value to be put at index location: 9
    >>> ulist[index1] = val
    >>> print(ulist)
    [1, 9, 3, 4, 5]
    >>>
```

Comment: Are you trying to understand how ``list.insert()`` works? What's the question here?

Comment: No! I know how list.insert() works.Its just that I want to know different ways to doing the same work as done by list.insert()

Comment: Then please [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30472442/edit) your question and clarify what you are asking. As it is your question is quite unclear.

Comment: @James Mills is the question better now? Please let me know how to improve.

Comment: Sadly no; Your question appears similar to an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- Hint: What are you wanting to do with your data structure? What are you inserting? What is the user input for? Describe the actual problem you're solving; not the problem you're currently having with ``list.insert()``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a list with one element to a slice of length zero:

```
>>> ulist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> ulist[2:2] = [9]
>>> ulist
[1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5]
```

### Explanation

You can assign a new list to a slice of an existing list.

Staring with your list:

```
>>> ulist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can slice it:

```
>>> ulist[2:4]
[3, 4]
```

You can assign a new list with an arbitrary size to this slice:

```
>>> ulist[2:4] = [10, 20, 30]
[1, 2, 10, 20, 30, 5]
```

This selects an empty slice:

```
>>> ulist[2:2]
[]
```

Assigning to it essentially inserts at index 2:

```
>>> ulist[2:2] = [100, 200, 300]
>>> ulist
[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 10, 20, 30, 5]
```

Using a list with only one element on the right hand side has the same
effect as `ulist.insert()`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I liked your explanation :-)

Comment: Glad that I could help. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use slice notation. This also has the advantage of leaving the original list intact:

```
>>> ulist = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> ulist2 = ulist[:2] + [9] + ulist[2:]
>>> ulist2
[1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5]
>>> ulist
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: It was nice but I was looking out for some explanation. Mike's ans just did that for me. Thanks